# Unable to install gittle library without root privileges

Tags: python, installation, pip, root, sudo

I followed this [link](https://github.com/FriendCode/gittle) to install `Gittle` library. But when I run a command

```
$ pip install gittle
```

I get an error:

> Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_victor
>   /gittle/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', 
>   open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
>   install --record /tmp/pip-aoyPEt-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally- managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_victor/gittle Storing debug log for failure in
>   /home/victor/.pip/pip.log

My `Python` version is `2.7.6`.

Comment: Does the log give any more details on what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @ ivan_pozdeev Well, I finally did it. Just running `sudo pip install gittle` did a trick.

Comment: Then please add this as a answer and accept it (for a badge and maybe some rep).

Comment: Btw, here's a fitting allusion: http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/bizarre_cathedral_95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You Need Root Privileges

Since you are installing sistem-wide libraries, these usually will be placed in directories which need root privileges for writing in them (for example anything under /usr/lib). Hence you need to either run the command as root:

```html
# pip install gittle
```

Or you can use sudo:

```bash
$ sudo pip install gittle
```

### What About Virtual Environments?

The more efficient/pythonic way to go about this would be using [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). This is especially true if you are installing project-specific libraries, which will most probably not be required by other projects. Another classical application of virtual environments is when you are working on a machine on which you don't have root privileges, say at university for example.

Once you set up a virtual environment, if you place it in a directory on which you have writing rights, you can run:

```bash
$ pip install gittle
```

to install `gittle` in this case.