# Using pip to install modules on remote server in specific directory

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, server

I'm trying to install BeautifulSoup on a remote server in my home directory. Do I use pip after ssh'ing onto the server or before? When I try before, it can't seem to find where to install BeautifulSoup:
"No such file or directory: '@server'", but if I try after logging into the server, I don't have permissions because it tries to do a system wide installation. Please let me know which process to follow, and any additional specific instructions for installing would be extremely helpful!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817341/is-it-possible-to-install-gittle-library/26817507#26817507.

Answer (score 0):

When using remote servers on which I don't have root permissions, I find it very useful to use a Python distribution like [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/). This is very easy to install and comes many of the popular Python packages (including BeautifulSoup). They also have support for virtual environments and additional python packages can also be installed easily.